# statfs /storage/sdcard0 failed, errno: 13

Tags: android

receiving this error in logcat with illegal argument exception

**statfs /storage/sdcard0 failed, errno: 13**

My code is

```
public double totalStorage() throws Exception {


        **stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());**
        return ((double) stat.getBlockSize()
                * (double) stat.getBlockCount());
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errno 13 indicates  "permission denied", meaning that you have insufficient privileges.

Comment: then how can i gain the privileges... and how can we get a list that shows the problem wrt to error no.

Comment: i have added the permission, now it is not throwing any exception. Thanks